# How can I print all the values that I input?

Tags: python, loops

I want to input customer's information at the end It only shows the last customer twice but I want to show both of them.

```
num = int(input()) #input number of customer

for customer in range(num):
    name = input()
    birth_year = int(input())
    gender = input()
    Age = 2020 - birth_year
print('---Customer Information---')
for output in range(num):
    print(name,'( age :',Age,')')
```

Output:

```
2
Danny
1993
male
John
2000
male
---Customer Information---
John ( age : 20 )
John ( age : 20 )
```

Desire output:

```
2
Danny
1993
male
John
2000
male
---Customer Information---
Danny ( age : 27 )
John ( age : 20 )
```

Comment: move `print(name,'(age :',Age,')')` inside 1st for loop remove 2nd for loop.

Comment: Your variables can only hold a single item of data. Python provides [a datatype that can hold more](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: In the first for loop when you get second person info it replace with first person info so, when you want to print both but you just have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `customers` **list**, which contains **dict** objects where the customers information is stored.

Here is an example:

```
num = int(input())  # quantity of customers


customers = []  # create a customers list
for customer in range(num):  # ask user to enter information about num customers
    # get customer data from user inputs
    name = input()
    birth_year = int(input())
    gender = input()
    age = 2020 - birth_year
    customers.append({"name": name, "birth_year": birth_year,
                      "gender": gender, "age": age})  # append the dict to the list

print('---Customer Information---')
for customer in customers:  # get every customer dict from the customers list
    print(customer["name"], '( age :', customer["age"], ')')  # and print it
```

Output:

```
2
John
14
M
Jane
20
F
---Customer Information---
John ( age : 2006 )
Jane ( age : 2000 )
```

Here is the `customers` list content (I will use [pprint Python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) to print it in a prettier way; you may use `print` if you want):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(customers)
[{'age': 2006, 'birth_year': 14, 'gender': 'M', 'name': 'John'},
 {'age': 2000, 'birth_year': 20, 'gender': 'F', 'name': 'Jane'}]
```

PS: I recommend you to read about [lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) and [dicts](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).